# program shows the requested resource is not available

Tags: java, servlets

Created servlet inside the java `resources/src/abcdservlet`. I'm trying to execute shows requested resources not available.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Abcd extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Abcd() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1> Welcome</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.print("</html>");


    }
}
```

Comment: did you declare servlet class in web.xml?

Comment: in web.xml i have added servlet name ,servlet mappling.

Comment: can you add web.xml file?